# Why won't my Gmail login work using PHP and CURL?

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I'm implementing one project using PHP, in that I want to login into a page automatically . 
The code is below.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$postdata="Email=$username&Passwd=$password&continue=https://www.mail.google.com";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $gacookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $gacookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$AskApache_result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $AskApache_result;
unlink($gacookie);
?>
```

But it won't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is “too much red” in the syntax highlighting. ;)

Comment: 'https://www.google.com" -> 'https://www.google.com', but expect that that is a mistype and not the reason it doens't work, otherwise at the top of your php file set: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('show_errors', 1); To see the errors in your document.

Comment: After executing this curl request, will it redirect to gmail or do we stay in our php app?

Answer (score 6):

First of all: "it won't work" does not give us much information and context to help you solving the problem.

To get your questions answered, please try to supply **details**, for example:

- What specific part is not working?
- Do you get any error messages?
- What operating system does you code run on?

It also helps to use a more **descriptive question title**. "PHP and CURL" does not give us much relevant information, whereas "How to solve error x123 when executing a CURL request" would be much more helpful.

Anyway. Looking at your code, there's at least **one** error:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com");
```

should be:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.google.com");
```

**Clarification:** the third parameter starts with a single quote and ends with a double quote.

Comment: I might be insanely blind, but I completely fail to spot the difference between those two lines of code

Comment: In the error, the third parameter starts with a single quote and ends with a double quote mark.

Comment: it even shows up clearly when you look at he code posted. It goes brown (as quoted text from 'https://www.google.com"); to the end of the example. Even the SO parser is missing closing quote here

Answer (score 2):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Is the most likely problem, option is disabled on most shared (& free) web hosts because it poses a security risk.